# How to listen sessionStorage in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, session-storage

I want to listen to every change inside `SessionStorage`. Is there a way to listen to it whenever it has changed?
I'm using react classes.

```
class Module extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      ....
    };
  }


  handleClick(e) {
    const value = e.currentTarget.textContent;
    sessionStorage.setItem("AnyValue", value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {this.props.id}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No ,u should make context or reducer for making change and expect rerender , if ur application has a lot of data probably u should use Redux .

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
    console.log("CHANGED!!!");    
  });
}
```

remember to unmount the listener

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('storage');
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work,  do you get the `console.log` when you make a change in your session storage?

Comment: I dont see the console log

Comment: I guess you have an issue somewhere else, and not with the listener above. Are you seeing your Session Storage update after you call `handleClick `?
You can observe Session Storage inside DevTools -> Application tab -> Session Storage.
Also if you go ahead and add/edit manually value in there you should see the console.log message being triggered.